# Help with this study of Bernoulli's ODE

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Let $(E)$ be the ODE$\space x'=a(t)x+b(t)x^\alpha,\alpha>0,$ $a,b:I\to\Bbb R$ are continuous functions. I have to find the $\alpha$ values such that (except the null function in $I$) the solutions of $(E)$ have the form $x:I\to(0,\infty)$ (positive solutions) or $x:I\to(-\infty,0)$ (negative solutions).

Let $f_\alpha:D=I\times[0,\infty)\to\Bbb R, f_\alpha(t,x)=b(t)x^\alpha+a(t)x$ is continuous in $D$ por every $\alpha>0.$ $\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}(t,x)=a(t)+\alpha b(t)x^{\alpha-1}$ is continuous in the open set $I\times(0,\infty)$ but not in $D$ if $\alpha\in(0,1)$. So, $f\in C(I\times(0,\infty),\Bbb R)\cap Lip_{Loc}(x,I\times(0,\infty))$, then $(E)$ satisfies the global uniqueness property in $I\times(0,\infty)$. But the Cauchy problem $(P) \{x'=\frac{3}{2}(\frac{x}{t}+x^{1/3}),x(1)=-1$ has $a(t)=\frac{3x}{2t}$ and $b(t)=\frac{3}{2}$, both continuous in $I=(0,\infty)$ and $\alpha=1/3\in(0,1)$ has a solution in $(0,\infty)$ given by

$x(t)=\{0$ if $0<t<e^{-1}$, $-\sqrt{(t·log(t)+t)^3}$ if $e^{-1}<t$, it doesn't satisfies that it's a $x:I\to(0,\infty)$ kind function.

So, what's wrong in my resolving or in the statement?

Comment: The range of $\alpha$ definitely depends on $a, b$. For example, if $b = 0$, any $\alpha $ suffices...